# Accessing .vsprops (Property Sheets) via VS Automation and Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2008, envdte, vsprops

I am trying to access user macros that are defined in a .vsprops (Property Sheet) that is used by a Visual Studio 2008 project.  I cannot find any documentation on accessing any information in a .vsprops file using VS automation and extension functionality (i.e., EnvDTE et al).  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [VCPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcpropertysheet) and other interfaces?